# Crystal Report - Exporting to PDF in both Landscape & Portrait

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, export-to-pdf

I've a crystal report which is having two pages; one in Portrait and the second one is in Landscape format. In report it looks fine but when I exporting it to a PDF, both pages got exported in Portrait format loosing some of the data. Can anyone solve my problem? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to do any single line of code follow this simple step
step:

1. Create first crystal report in Portrait format and this is default format of report.
2. Create a second crystal report in landscape. To do this you should right on the second crystal report Design->page set-up->orientation->choose landscape
3. Create a third crystal report that is final report in that add in detail section first and second report as a sub report. Just right click insert->sub report
4. In the final report just right click on section export on detail section of second report select section expert->paging->landscape your job is done.
5. Then export that final report to PDF in your code.

Answer (score 4):

1. Export first page as PDF in Portrait
2. Export second page as PDF in Landscape
3. Combine the two PDF's using a third party library

It's a bit tricky, if you're using ExportToStream because the main public one is

```
report.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType formatType)
```

which ignores FormatOptions. Instead you will need to use

```
report.FormatEngine.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext)
```

This code should do what you want (using PdfSharp to combine):

```
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using CrystalDecisions.Shared;
using PdfSharp.Pdf;
using PdfSharp.Pdf.IO;
...
using (var report = new ReportClass { FileName = Server.MapPath("/Crystal/Reports/DosBatches.rpt") })
{
    report.Load();

    /* set data source connections */
    /* set parameters */

    // export the first page
    report.PrintOptions.PaperOrientation = PaperOrientation.Portrait;
    var exportOptions1 = new ExportOptions
    {
        ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat,
        FormatOptions = new PdfFormatOptions { UsePageRange = true, FirstPageNumber = 1, LastPageNumber = 1 }
    };
    exportRequestContext.ExportInfo = exportOptions1;
    var stream1 = report.FormatEngine.ExportToStream(exportRequestContext);
    stream1.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    // export the second page
    report.PrintOptions.PaperOrientation = PaperOrientation.Landscape;
    var exportOptions2 = new ExportOptions
    {
        ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat,
        FormatOptions = new PdfFormatOptions { UsePageRange = true, FirstPageNumber = 2, LastPageNumber = 2 }
    };
    exportRequestContext.ExportInfo = exportOptions2;
    var stream2 = report.FormatEngine.ExportToStream(exportRequestContext);
    stream2.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    // merge the two PDF streams
    var combinedPdf = new PdfDocument();
    foreach (PdfPage page in PdfReader.Open(stream1, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import).Pages)
        combinedPdf.AddPage(page);
    foreach (PdfPage page in PdfReader.Open(stream2, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import).Pages)
        combinedPdf.AddPage(page);

    // probably not the most efficient, but works
    var output = new MemoryStream();
    combinedPdf.Save(output, false);
    return new FileStreamResult(output, "application/pdf");
}
```